# Installing Branch into Visual Studio Cordova project

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, branch.io

I am trying to install [Branch](https://branch.io/) into my Visual Studio 2015 Cordova project.  I have made it thru all the beginning [steps](https://start.branch.io/#/integrate-sdk/steps) and now trying to integrate the SDK.  I placed the following into the Git command window off the config.xml file but just receive an error saying the plugin failed to download.  There is no more information in the output windows as to why it failed.

```
https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Cordova-Ionic-PhoneGap-Deferred-Deep-Linking-SDK.git --variable BRANCH_KEY=myKey --variable URI_SCHEME=myUri
```

My project was set to CLI 6.2.0 and I have now updated it to 6.3.0 to see if that would fix it but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was manually adding the plugin to the config.xml file instead of using the command window.  The lines I added were:

```
<plugin name="cordova-ionic-phonegap-branch-deep-linking" src="https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Cordova-Ionic-PhoneGap-Deferred-Deep-Linking-SDK.git">
   <variable name="BRANCH_KEY" value="myKey" />
   <variable name="URI_SCHEME" value="myUri" /></plugin>
```

This technically did not work at first for some reason.  I attempted the build and nothing happened.  After looking into some other paths and then coming back to this I then switched my build target from android to windows and voila.  The plugin was pulled into my project however, I did get an error which appears to be  windows related.  When I switch the project back to Android it builds fine.  I will have to look into the separate error now, but this does fix this issue.  Not 100% sure why the Cordova project would not pull the plugin into the project until switched, but must have been with the cache.

Comment: Alex from Branch.io here: I don't believe we have ever tested our Cordova SDK with Visual Studio, so this is a new use case for us. Glad you were able to get it working! Feel free to [submit a PR](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/cordova-ionic-phonegap-branch-deep-linking) with any updates if you are able to figure out what was causing the issue.